# Cannot get the secondSpinner to refresh itself

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

Can someone look at my code its really simple created just to practice my skills. But the language spinner works but the gender spinner is buggy. It will work once i change the language then change the gender and then go back to the gender i originally wanted. Code is shown. Thanks. Have tried putting onItemSelected() for spinnerGen, it does not solve the issue. Researching about this since last night cant find any solution

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnGo, btnAbout;
private Spinner spinner, spinnerGen;
private EditText addName;

private ArrayList<String> options;
private ArrayList<String> optionsGen;
private String allOption = "";
private String genOption = "";
private String genOptionSec = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initPage();


    options = new ArrayList<>();
    options.add("English");
    options.add("Bengali");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    optionsGen = new ArrayList<>();
    optionsGen.add("Male");
    optionsGen.add("Female");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterGen = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, optionsGen);
    spinnerGen.setAdapter(adapterGen);
    adapterGen.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    adapterGen.notifyDataSetChanged();


    spinnerMethod();


}


private void initPage() {
    btnGo = findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    btnAbout = findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinnerGen = findViewById(R.id.spinnerGen);
    addName = findViewById(R.id.addName);

}

public void spinnerMethod() {
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            allOption = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            switch (allOption) {
                case "English" :
                    newMethodEnglish();
                    break;
                case "Bengali" :
                    newMethodBengali();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


}

public void newMethodEnglish() {
   genOption = spinnerGen.getSelectedItem().toString();
   switch (genOption) {
       case "Male":
           onClickEngMale(); //In these method Im just navigating to another activity
           break;
       case "Female":
           OnClickEngFemale();
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
}

public void OnClickEngFemale() {
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String femaleData = addName.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EngFemale.class);
            intent.putExtra("DataFemale", femaleData);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void onClickEngMale() {
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String maleData = addName.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EngMale.class);
            intent.putExtra("Data", maleData);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void newMethodBengali() {
    genOptionSec = spinnerGen.getSelectedItem().toString();

    switch (genOptionSec){
        case "Male":
            onClickBanMale();
            break;
        case "Female":
            onClickBanFemale();
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void onClickBanMale() {
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String maleData = addName.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BanMale.class);
            intent.putExtra("DataBan", maleData);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void onClickBanFemale() {
    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String femaleData = addName.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BanFemale.class);
            intent.putExtra("BanFemale", femaleData);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You did not tell how the spinners should behave.

Comment: I don't want it to behave i just want to take the output. So if i select english + male i want to navigate to a page similarly if i select english + female i want it to navigate to another

Comment: `Have tried putting onItemSelected() for spinnerGen, it does solve the issue. ` onItemSelected of spinnerGen looks a good place to go to a next page. And if you tell us that it solves the issue then what is the problem?

Comment: sorry bro i made an error. It does not solve the problem.